# Android: How to catch QuiltView item onClick

Tags: android, imageview, onclicklistener, quiltview

I`m using QuiltView library right now in my app. I have filled images all items. The problem is catch on item click event on quiltview.

```
    quiltView = (QuiltView) findViewById(R.id.quilt);
    quiltView.setChildPadding(5);
    imageArray = new int[]{R.drawable.mayer, R.drawable.mayer1};
    addTestQuilts(200);

    public void addTestQuilts(int num){
    final ArrayList<ImageView> images = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.animation);
        final ImageView image = new ImageView(HomeActivity.this);
        if(i % 2 == 0) {
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.mayer);
        }
        else
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.mayer1);
        images.add(image);
    }
    quiltView.addPatchImages(images);
```

I wanna change imageView resource to another image when item is clicked. Any help will be appreciated.